# How to get the released package's .dsc file the Debian way?

Tags: debian, patch-management

```
DSCURL="$(wget -qO- "https://packages.debian.org/${SUITE}/${PKG}" \
    | grep -o 'http.*\.dsc">\[' | cut -d'"' -f1)"
[ -z "$DSCURL" ] && die 2 "no .dsc"
dget ${ALLOW_UNAUTH} -x "$DSCURL" 2> "$TEMP"
```

I am looking for the Debain-way of getting a source package from jessie to download it by `dget -x $DSCURL`. It is for [backporting](https://gist.github.com/szepeviktor/11087679) so `apt-get source` is not a solution, it would interfere with the apt system on wheezy.
I am doing it now by parsing the Debian webpage. I couldn't found the right [Debian API](http://sources.debian.net/doc/api/).

Comment: I don't understand how does it interfere. You can have multiple `deb-src` lines and select which one you want to use with `apt-get source -t jessie`, for example. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: I'd like to use a tool that queries Debian's databases without downloading the whole source package list of several `${SUITE}`-s

Comment: e.g. jessie source package lists are 195k + 29,960k + 398k

Answer (score 2):

[`apt-get source -t jessie dpkg`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=debootstrap&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) **is one way** to go:

To quote the relevant sections from the manpage

```
       Source packages are tracked separately from binary packages via
       deb-src lines in the sources.list(5) file. This means that you will
       need to add such a line for each repository you want to get sources
       from; otherwise you will probably get either the wrong (too old/too
       new) source versions or none at all.
```

And also:

```
   -t, --target-release, --default-release
       This option controls the default input to the policy engine; it
       creates a default pin at priority 990 using the specified release
       string. This overrides the general settings in
       /etc/apt/preferences. Specifically pinned packages are not affected
       by the value of this option. In short, this option lets you have
       simple control over which distribution packages will be retrieved
       from. Some common examples might be -t '2.1*', -t unstable or -t
       sid. Configuration Item: APT::Default-Release; see also the
       apt_preferences(5) manual page.
```

Another option is to use [`debootstrap`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=debootstrap&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) and create a complete chroot.

Do not forget to use stuff like [`pbuilder`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pbuilder&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en) to have reliable builds of your package.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I would like to avoid downloading source package lists. [These backports](http://mirror.szepe.net/debian/) are needed only for running my vps-s.

Comment: Wait what? You don't want `apt-get update` to get a few KB of data and therefore don't want the `deb-src` entry? That is how I read your answer but I think i misinterpreted that

Comment: And another outdated: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/debget

Comment: An work-in-progress SOAP API https://wiki.debian.org/qa.debian.org/pts/SoapInterface

Comment: So you found 2 outdated solutions and one that is not yet implemented aside from the one "just works". :)

Comment: Sorry. I've found the solution. Look! qa.debian.org/cgi-bin/dcontrol But somehow testin/jessie is missing from this system!